# Use specific IP from list of multiple IPs as the source IP for a Solaris host

Tags: solaris, ip, routing, source, iproute

My solaris server host `webhost` has many IP addresses a few are listed below.

```
$ ifconfig -a

lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
ipmp0: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.6 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
        groupname ipmp0
ipmp0:1: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.142 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
ipmp0:2: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.143 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
ipmp0:3: flags=108001000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,IPMP,PHYSRUNNING> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.61.15.144 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255
.....
```

Any traffic that is sent from `webhost` to any remote host must always use this IP `inet 10.61.15.6 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255` source IP.

The reason is that the firewall is open "ONLY" from source `inet 10.61.15.6 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.61.5.255` to remote hosts while other IP addresses do not have the firewall open.

Can you please suggest how can we achieve this in solaris?

Comment: Which version of Solaris?  What do all your network interfaces look like?  Depending on your network configuration, you may do better with network aggregation instead of IPMP.